# Are these two versions of the Hanson-Wright Inequality Equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, quadratic-forms, distribution-tails

I have a question regarding the following two different versions of the Hanson-Wright inequality for estimating the tail behavior of (sub-)Gaussian chaos (i.e. quadratic forms). The first is Thm. 6.2.1 in Vershynin's book "High-dimensional Probability," and it is as follows:

Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with independent, mean zero, sub-gaussian coordinates. Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Then, for every $t \geq 0$, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X^TAX - \mathbb{E}X^TAX|\geq t) \leq 2 \exp\left(-c \min\left\{\frac{t^2}{K^4\|A\|_F^2}, \frac{t}{K^2\|A\|_{op}}\right\}\right),$$
where $K = \max_{i} \|X_i\|_{\phi_2}$. Here $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm and $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ the (spectral) operator norm.

The second I have seen in a couple places, most recently in [this blog post](https://www.ethanepperly.com/index.php/2022/10/04/note-to-self-hanson-wright-inequality/), which references Vershynin, and is as follows:

Let $x$ be a random vector with independent, centered $\nu$-subgaussian entries and let $A$ be a square matrix. Then
$$ \mathbb{P}(|x^TAx - \mathbb{E}[x^TAx]| \geq t) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{c \cdot t^2}{\nu^2 \|A\|_F^2 + \nu\|A\|_{op} t}\right),$$
where $c > 0$ is a constant not depending on $\nu, x, t,$ or $A$.

My question is, are these two versions equivalent? Both describe the combination of lighter and heavier tails, just using different methods, I guess, but are they interchangeable? I am familiar with the two definitions of sub-gaussian variables which are used here, but I have some trouble comparing them, and I am unsure where the $K$ from the first version or the "$\min$" go... Any help would be appreciated.

I am especially interested if one can recover the minimum version from the sum version while monitoring how the constants change.

Comment: The $\nu$ seems to be $K^2$. The second inequality seems to be implied by the first one with the first $c$ being half of the second $c$, but I don't know if you can derive the first one from the second one. Maybe someone else knows.

Comment: @BrunoB I don't think $\nu$ is exactly $K^2$. For example, $\|X\|_{\psi_2} = \sqrt{8/3}$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, but $\nu$ would be equal to the variance, i.e. $\nu = 1$ in this case...